# Is it possible to write a generall derived instance for a data type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, derived-instances

I require comparison between two Htrees and to do so i implemented my own comparison function which i use together with sortBy, however i want to implement a derived instance of the Eq and Ord classes but the amount of cases  needed to cover all possible combinations makes it impractical.

```
data Htree a b = Leaf a b
         | Branch a (Htree a b) (Htree a b)
          deriving (Show)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Htree a b) where 

     (Leaf weight1 _ ) == (Leaf weight2 _) = weight1 == weight2
     (Branch weight1 _ _) == (Leaf weight2 _) = weight1 == weight2
     (Leaf weight1 _ ) == (Branch weight2 _ _) = weight1 == weight2
     (Branch weight1 _ _) == (Branch weight2 _ _) = weight1 == weight2
```

As you can see, i just want to compare a single part of the Htree, Which will be an Integer in the actual code, and i need to write four cases for it. is there a way to generalize this so i can write it in just a single case? 
If i compare two Htree, compare their Integer parts?

what i currently use to compare two htree is:

```
comparison :: Htree Integer (Maybe Char) -> Htree Integer (Maybe Char) -> 
Ordering
comparison w1 w2 = if(getWeight(w1) > getWeight(w2)) then GT
               else if(getWeight(w1) < getWeight(w2)) then LT
               else EQ
```

where getWeight is defined as:

```
getWeight :: Htree Integer (Maybe Char) -> Integer
getWeight(Leaf weight _) = weight
getWeight(Branch weight _ _) = weight
```

Comment: This is probably not a [lawful Eq instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Eq.html#t:Eq). Assuming that you allow consumers of your tree to look at anything but the weight of a node, you break the "Substitutivity" law. Why do you need these Eq and Ord instances? Look for alternative approaches to whatever goal you had in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what you want, first write a more general version (that is, a polymorphic version) of `getWeight`, which only requires rewriting the type signature:

```
getWeight :: Htree a b -> a
getWeight(Leaf weight _) = weight
getWeight(Branch weight _ _) = weight
```

Then you can do the following (after `import`ing the `on` function from `Data.Function` - I have also rewritten to make them point free as recommended by @FyodorSolkin)

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Htree a b) where
    (==) = (==) `on` getWeight

instance (Ord a) => Ord (Htree a b) where
    compare = compare `on` getWeight
```

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to write them point-free, e.g. ``compare = compare `on` getWeight``

Comment: good point @FyodorSoikin, don't know how I missed that. I will edit and give you credit :)

Comment: Even better: `compare = comparing getWeight`.

Comment: that looks good @Alec, I've actually never come across `comparing` before. It turns out trying to answer what questions I can on here is actually good for learning more about Haskell myself :)